# Can you obtain OCI for minor US born child if you do not have a valid H1B visa stamped on passport?

Tags: usa, visa, citizenship, passport, india

To apply OCI for minor born in USA, using VFS San Francisco - ( not CKGS ).

The document requirement clearly states under passport section "In case of a Minor, parents are requested to provide a copy of parents' passport & copy of parent’s valid Visa status in the USA ( for Non-USA passport holders)".

H1B visa stamp on passport has expired. We do have valid I-797 (H1B). What does valid Visa status in the US mean ? Can we obtain OCI with valid I-797 but expired H1B stamp ? Anyone with first hand real life experience? Thank you.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your valid immigration status in the US is attested by your valid I-94 form.  If you don't have a paper copy because your most recent I-94 was issued electronically by CBP when you entered the US, you should to be able to print one by visiting https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov.  If your most recent I-94 was issued on paper but you've lost it, you can apply for a replacement.

Comment: USCIS also issues I-94s with an I-797A. That might be what he has.